# Assign a Razor Function to a JavaScript Variable?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, razor

I have a JavaScript Function where I want to call a `Razor C# Function` in it, I know it's easy in HTML but in JavaScript i'm getting many compilation errors I tried the `<text> tag` trick but nothing worked.

getHTML is My JavaScript Function and getPageSource is a C# function that returns a string:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function getHTML() {
            var html = "@getPageSource("http://www.google.com")" ;       
            alert(html);
        }

</script>
```

where `@getPageSource` is defined above the html and is working well within the HTML code

Is there any way to assign some Razor Code to a JavaScript Variable ?

Comment: As far as I know, Razor code is server-side code. You can't execute that from JavaScript (Client-side)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't execute server side functions in client side. Razor is only used to give you the ability to have some logic while generating the HTML code to be returned, in the server.

If that is a C# function that returns a String, you should wrap it inside quotes or it won't be interpreted as a Javascript string when the browser is parsing your response.

```
var html = '@getPageSource("http://www.google.com")';
```

Remember that if your getPageSource("http://www.google.com") returns a string with quotes inside, the javascript will be inconsistent and unable to create your JS string. Imagine that your method returned `<div> ' hello ' </div>`. That would end up like:

```
var html = '<div> ' hello ' </div>';
```

See the problem?

See this to convert a HTML C# String into one that can be used as a JS String.
http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/722/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-c-so-that-the-string-can-be-used-in-javascript

You must replace every `'` with `\\'` . Remember that your string will be completely passed to the HTML code. Imagine that your code was returning `"It's blue"`. When wrote in the HTML it would end as `var str = 'It's blue'` (notice that `"s blue"` will be considered outside the string and will give a parsing error by the browser).
To write that in JS you needed something like `var str = 'It\'s blue'` so the browser will know that quote is not an ending string quote but it's contained in the string.
To include the dash in C#, your returning string must be `"It\\'s blue"` once the replace of `'` with `\\'`

Comment: I get a ReferenceError: getHTML is not defined error after wrapping inside the quotes ?

Comment: I added further explanation thay may be causing your problem

Comment: But getPageSource is a C# or a Javascript function? Based on your comments bellow I'm starting to assume it is a JS function?

Comment: getPageSource is definetly C# here it's implementation
'
@functions{
    string getPageSource(string URL)
    {
        System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string strSource = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
        webClient.Dispose();
        return strSource;
    }
    
    }
'

Comment: I added further explanation at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Is `getPageSource()` a JavaScript function or a C# function?

If it's JavaScript you don't need to prefix with `@`. If it's C# then just add quotes:

```
var html = '@getPageSource("http://www.google.com")';
```

Comment: The `@` is part of the Razor syntax. `getPageSource` is a server-side function, and the `@` is used in views to indicate that the following characters aren't text, but a function.

Comment: when I do what you said i end up with
 ReferenceError: getHTML is not defined

Comment: @Cerbrus I know but the sentence "...@getPageSource is defined above the html and is working well within the HTML code." makes me think it _may_ be even JavaScript.

Comment: @user1358763 What getPageSource is? Post its definition!

Comment: @Adriano: `function @test(){alert(1);} --> 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`
You can't define functions starting with `@`. That, and he tagged the question with Razor, and he specifically asked _"Is there any way to assign some Razor Code to a Javascript Variable ?"_ I'm pretty sure it's a Razor function.

Comment: @Cerbrus I may agree but I wasn't sure, that's why I posted both answers.